# Adding an ASP:DropDownList to select upload folder for ASPxUploadControl

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, dropdownbox

I have a web form that uses a DevExpress ASPxUploadControl (v 8.3) to let our users upload documents to our server.  I'm working on an enhancement that will allow them to select an upload folder for the document.  These are not physical folders, but logical folders.  I've added an ASP:DropDownList to the form, which I populate from the database with the names of the folders that user has set up.  If the user selects the folder and then the attachment everything works fine.  However, if they select the file to upload and then the folder, the file is uploaded automatically once the file has been selected, rather than waiting for them to click the Upload link.  This does not allow them to change if they've selected the wrong document.  Also, the old (last) value selected from the dropdownlist is used - it is not being updated to reflect the new choice  I suspect there is a clash between server-side events and client-side events.  Following is the relevant code.  How can I prevent the page from automatically uploading the document?

Thanks!
Mike

```
<td class="style6" valign="middle">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Panel ID="Panel3" colspan="2" runat="server" Height="83px" Width="125px"
                    Style="margin-top: 0px">
                                <dxuc:ASPxUploadControl ID="uplImage" runat="server" 
                                ClientInstanceName="uploader" Font-Size="Medium" Height="84px" 
                                OnFileUploadComplete="uplImage_FileUploadComplete" ShowUploadButton="True" 
                                Size="50" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 2px;">

                                    <ValidationSettings AllowedContentTypes="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/pjpeg,application/pdf,application/rtf,application/msword,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/csv,text/plain,text/csv,text/richtext,text/rtf,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, audio/wav" MaxFileSize="4096000">
                                        <ErrorStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />
                                    </ValidationSettings>
                                    <ClientSideEvents FileUploadComplete="function(s, e) {
                            if(e.isValid)
                            {
                                if(e.errorText != ''){
                                    alert(e.errorText);
                                } else {
                                    alert(e.callbackData);
                                }
                            }
                        }" />
                        <ValidationSettings AllowedContentTypes="image/jpeg, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/pdf, application/rtf, application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/csv, text/plain, text/csv, text/richtext, text/rtf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, audio/wav"
                            MaxFileSize="4096000">
                            <ErrorStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />
                        </ValidationSettings>
                                    <ClientSideEvents FilesUploadComplete="function(s, e) {}" FileUploadComplete="function(s, e) {
                            if(e.isValid)
                            {
                                if(e.errorText != ''){
                                    alert(e.errorText);
                                } else {
                                    alert(e.callbackData);
                                }
                            }
                        }" FileUploadStart="function(s, e) {}" />

                    </dxuc:ASPxUploadControl>

                </asp:Panel>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="txtnote" align="center" style="height: 18px">
                Allowed file types: jpeg, gif, pdf, rtf, doc, docx, txt, csv, xls, xlsx, wav
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="txtnote" align="center" style="height: 10px">
                Maximum file size: 4Mb
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input id="chkPrivate" name="chkPrivate"  value="1" type="checkbox"/>Private 
            (checking Private prevents Mgmt Co &amp;Assn from viewing attachment via client 
            login.)</td></tr>            
        <tr class="aligncenter">
            <th class="style5" align="center" colspan="2">
                &nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="aligncenter">
            <th class="style5" align="center" colspan="2">
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px">
                    <%--<dxe:ASPxButton ID="Button1" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Text="Cancel">
                        <Paddings PaddingLeft="10px" PaddingRight="10px" />
                    </dxe:ASPxButton>--%>
                    <input type="button" id="btnReturn" class="frmBtnCommon" value="Back To Case" onclick="ReturnToCase();" />
                </asp:Panel>

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim DAL As New DataAccessLayer
        Dim dtFolders As New DataTable

        GlobalVar.LoadData(Session("UserPKey"))

        Session("CurrentPage") = "CaseAttchmt.aspx"
        If Session("LoggedOn") = True And GlobalVar.ConnectString <> "" Then
            CSSDefaultHTML = Session("CSS_Default")
            DefaultIPHTML = Application("DefaultIP")
        End If

        SelKey = Request.QueryString("Case")

        Header1.ConnectionStr = GlobalVar.ConnectString
        Header1.HDLawFirm = GlobalVar.LawFirmDir
        Header1.InsertHeader("Add File to a Case", 0, 0, SelKey, "width=100% align=center")
        ClientKey = Session("ClientKey")
        UploadDirectory = GlobalVar.LawFirmDir & "AttachFiles/Case" & Trim(Str(SelKey)) & "/"

        If System.IO.Directory.Exists(GlobalVar.LawFirmDir & "AttachFiles/") = False Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(GlobalVar.LawFirmDir & "AttachFiles")
        End If

        If System.IO.Directory.Exists(GlobalVar.LawFirmDir & "AttachFiles/Case" & Trim(Str(SelKey))) = False Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(GlobalVar.LawFirmDir & "AttachFiles/Case" & Trim(Str(SelKey)))
        End If

        GlobalVar.SaveData(Session("UserPKey"))

        dtFolders = DAL.GetClientFolders(Session("ClientKey"))
        ddlFolders.DataSource = dtFolders
        Dim lstFolders As ListItem
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim intValue As Integer
        Dim strText As String

        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            ddlFolders.Items.Clear
            intValue = 0
            strText = "Attachments"
            lstFolders = New ListItem(strText, intValue)
            ddlFolders.Items.Add(lstFolders)

            For i = 0 to dtFolders.Rows.Count - 1
                intValue = dtFolders.Rows(i).Item("pKey")
                strText = dtFolders.Rows(i).Item("FolderName")
                lstFolders = New ListItem(strText, intValue)
                ddlFolders.Items.Add(lstFolders)
            Next
            ddlFolders.SelectedIndex = 0
            Session("FolderKey") = 0
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Function SavePostedFile() As String

        Dim filename As String = ""
        Dim tempFileName As String = ""
        SelKey = Session("SelKey")
        If Len(Trim(Session("ClientKey"))) = 4 then
            UploadDirectory = "~/DATA/AR00" & Session("ClientKey") & "/AttachFiles/Case" & Trim(Str(SelKey)) & "/"
        Else
            UploadDirectory = "~/DATA/" & Trim(Session("LawFirm")) & "/AttachFiles/Case" & Trim(Str(SelKey)) & "/"
        End If

        filename = Trim(uplImage.FileName)

        If filename <> "" Then
            tempFileName = MapPath(UploadDirectory) & filename
            uplImage.SaveAs(tempFileName)
        End If
        Return tempFileName

    End Function

    Protected Sub uplImage_FileUploadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FileUploadCompleteEventArgs)

        Dim FileExists As Boolean = False
        UploadDirectory = "~/DATA/" & Trim(Session("LawFirm")) & "/AttachFiles/Case" & Trim(Str(Session("SelKey"))) & "/"

        Dim FilePath As String = MapPath(UploadDirectory) & Trim(uplImage.FileName)

        FileExists = CheckForFile(FilePath)

        'urk : Added validation for checking filename length and filesize being uploaded 06/01/2010.
        If (e.IsValid) Then
            If (e.UploadedFile.FileName.Length > 100) Then
                e.ErrorText = "The file name cannot be more than 100 characters long.  Please shorten and retry."
            ElseIf (e.UploadedFile.FileName.Contains("'") Or e.UploadedFile.FileName.Contains("&")) Then
                e.ErrorText = "The file name cannot contain the apostrophe or ampersand characters."
            ElseIf (e.UploadedFile.FileName.EndsWith(".aspx")) Or (e.UploadedFile.FileName.EndsWith(".ASPX")) Then
                e.ErrorText = ".aspx files are not allowed for upload."
            ElseIf FileExists = True Then
                e.ErrorText = "A file with this name has already been uploaded.  Please rename and try again."
            Else
                e.CallbackData = SavePostedFile()
                If e.CallbackData <> "" Then
                    s_UpdateAttachData()
                End If
                e.CallbackData = "File: '" + e.UploadedFile.FileName + "' uploaded successfully."
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub s_UpdateAttachData()

        Dim i_date As DateTime = Now.Date
        Dim DAL As New DataAccessLayer

        ClientKey = Session("ClientKey")
        Dim pPrintBy As Integer = Session("UserPKey")
        Dim PrintDate As DateTime = Now
        Dim s As Boolean
        Dim FullAttchPath As String

        If Len(trim(ClientKey)) = 1 Then
            FullAttchPath = "DATA/AR00000" + ClientKey.ToString + "/AttachFiles/Case" + SelKey.ToString + "/" + Trim(uplImage.FileName)
        ElseIf Len(Trim(ClientKey)) = 4 then
            FullAttchPath = "DATA/AR00" + ClientKey.ToString + "/AttachFiles/Case" + SelKey.ToString + "/" + Trim(uplImage.FileName)
        Else
            FullAttchPath = "DATA/AR0" + ClientKey.ToString + "/AttachFiles/Case" + SelKey.ToString + "/" + Trim(uplImage.FileName)
        End If
        If Request.Form("chkPrivate") <> "" Then
            s = 1
        Else
            s = 0
        End If

        DAL.InsertCasesAttachPKey(ClientKey, SelKey, Trim(uplImage.FileName), Trim(uplImage.FileName), pPrintBy, PrintDate, s, FullAttchPath, Session("FolderKey"))

    End Sub

    Protected Function CheckForFile(ByVal Filename As String) As Boolean

        If File.Exists(Filename) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If

    End Function

        Protected Sub ddlFolders_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlFolders.SelectedIndexChanged

        Session("FolderKey") = ddlFolders.SelectedValue

    End Sub
```